# What happen if two app version review at same time in google play?

Tags: android, console, google-play, app-update

I published my app version code 180 in google play. Its in review and updated same apk made some changes and app version code is 181 to google play. Both two apps review in the google play console. So which one is update first ?

Production

181 - in review
180 - in review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be 180 first and then 181, but I think you should reject build 180 all together and just leave 181 because anyways 181 will have changes of 180, so its better to avoid waiting for to review.

Comment: so its not a problem right ? .Also i turned on manage publishing. when apps review completed. shall i push live to 181 version ?

Comment: any way google show user an app as update by comparing versionCode only , if 181 is already live then 180 will not be shown to user as an update any ways